# Absolute ("/foo") and relative ("../foo") file names. What is the "foo" category called?

Tags: directory, terminology, filenames, relative-path, absolute-path

There are three types of file names

First (rooted below some kind of "current working directory")

```
../foo 
./foo
bar/foo # really in this group?
```

And (rooted in an absolute path, independent of the CWD)

```
/foo
/bar/foo
```

And (independent of the CWD and independent of any absolute path)

```
foo
bar/foo # really in this group?
```

I'm unsure where to put the `bar/foo` thing in. Is there a general naming convention for these three categories? Or are there more of them?

Comment: Is this really a *programming* question ?

Comment: @Paul R: it's a good question if you want to know how to name your variables :)

Comment: Re: *And (independent of the CWD and independent of any absolute path)*   Those are *not* independant of the cwd, they are **in** the cwd and thus relative.

Comment: @Synetech but why then typing "ls" finds a program file in "/usr/bin/" instead of "." ? It does not look in the CWD, but in directories of $PATH. Which indicates that names of the form "foo" are of some other category. Relative perhaps, but do they deserve a special name like "context-relative" or something?

Answer (score 1):

`foo` is also a relative pathname. Any path not containing a directory separator is relative to the current directory `.`

In another taxonomy, you could call `foo` a basename; then `bar/foo` moves to the first category.

Comment: "Any path not containing a directory separator is relative to the current directory .". But executing "echo" finds /bin/echo. Not necessarily "./echo". While when I execute "./echo", it doesn'T find "/bin/echo". So "foo" and "./foo" seem to be different; the former doesn't seem to be relative to the current directory.

Comment: "foo" seems to be like "relative to something context dependent, but not necessarily the CWD". For example, program execution uses PATH, library loading uses, among others, LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: @litb: alright, but this behavior is only found in a select number of cases (shell commands etc.) and I've never seen a name for this, so you can coin one yourself. What about "search-path relative"?